# Undefined reference error when compiling arrow scroll menu

Tags: c

So I have this code which I found from a random guy on youtube for a arrow scroll menu. It is working for him but for me I have the *undefined reference to arrow* error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>

void menu()
{system("cls");
    int position = 1;
    int keypress = 0;

    #define MAX 4
    #define MIN 1
    while(keypress != 13){
            system("cls");
    arrow(1,position); printf("Hello world!\n");
    arrow(2,position); printf("Hello");

    keypress = getch();

    if(keypress == 80 && position != 4){
        position++;
    }else if(keypress == 72 && position !=1){
    position --;
    }else {
    position = position;}
    return 0;
}

void arrow(int realposition, int arrowposition){
if(realposition == arrowposition){
   printf("-->");}
   else{
    printf("   ");}
   }}
```

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: Why? A function must be declared before it is used. That's the problem in the other post and seems to be the problem here. Have you tried the answers in the linked post?

Comment: After a few more tries and operations it worked. Thank you it really helped me